# webpack css-loader removing leading slash in url()

Tags: webpack, create-react-app, css-loader, react-app-rewired

I have a path set in a scss file to a resource I need referenced off the root of the domain. The problem is css-loader removes the leading slash during build, even with the option `{ url: false }`.

```
url('/path/to/file') -> url('path/to/file')
```

Any ideas why it does this, and how to avoid? Thanks.

**Edit:** Should mention I'm using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) with [react-app-rewired](https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired). My configs:

```
// config-overrides.js

const { override, adjustStyleLoaders } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  adjustStyleLoaders(({ use: [, css] }) => {
    css.options = { ...css.options, url: false };
  })
);
```

`console.log` of style loaders:

```
[
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
    options: {}
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { importLoaders: 1, sourceMap: true, url: false }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js',
    options: { ident: 'postcss', plugins: [Function: plugins], sourceMap: true }
  }
]

[
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
    options: {}
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: {
      importLoaders: 1,
      sourceMap: true,
      modules: [Object],
      url: false
    }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js',
    options: { ident: 'postcss', plugins: [Function: plugins], sourceMap: true }
  }
]

[
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
    options: {}
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { importLoaders: 3, sourceMap: true, url: false }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js',
    options: { ident: 'postcss', plugins: [Function: plugins], sourceMap: true }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js',
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      root: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/src'
    }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { sourceMap: true }
  }
]

[
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js',
    options: {}
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: {
      importLoaders: 3,
      sourceMap: true,
      modules: [Object],
      url: false
    }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js',
    options: { ident: 'postcss', plugins: [Function: plugins], sourceMap: true }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/resolve-url-loader/index.js',
    options: {
      sourceMap: true,
      root: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/src'
    }
  },
  {
    loader: '/Users/323782896/Documents/Projects/ReactUI/node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js',
    options: { sourceMap: true }
  }
]
```

Could it possibly be one of the other loaders responsible?

Comment: Normally with `{ url: false }` it doesn't touch your path. Can you show your config file?

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm using create-react-app (v4) with react-app-rewired. Updated the question with more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the `resolve-url-loader`, particularly the [root](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader/blob/v5/packages/resolve-url-loader/README.md#options) option set to the project `src` by CRA.

> Similar to the (now defunct) option in css-loader.
> This string, possibly empty, is prepended to absolute URIs.
> Absolute URIs are only processed if this option is set.

Not sure exactly how or when this changed, but this only became a problem for me after upgrading to CRA v4. In any case, the following adjustment (removing the `root` option) seemed to do the trick:

```
// config-overrides.js

const { override, adjustStyleLoaders } = require('customize-cra');

module.exports = override(
  adjustStyleLoaders(({ use: [miniExtract, css, postcss, resolveUrl, sass] }) => {
    css.options = { ...css.options, url: false };
    if (resolveUrl) {
      delete resolveUrl.options.root;
    }
  })
);
```